# Is there a way to sample a texture in GLSL into a small array?

Tags: glsl

I have made a terrain shader where the vertex stage samples a heightmap, and in order to calculate normals I need the neighbouring pixels too.  I get the height by using TexelFetch() for the current vertex and it's neighbours, but that involves calling TextelFetch() five times.  I also have some code that performs bicubic interpolation between the vertices (if they are tessellated)  which for that, involves sampling 16 points of the texture, all with the current vertex as the centre.

Instead of calling TexelFetch() 16 times per vertex, can I retrieve a sample area of a texture and store it in an array of vec4's?  Something like this;

```
vec4[16] region = TexelFetch(heightmap, startX, startY, rectWidth, rectHeight)
```

That's probably not the correct syntax or anything but you get the idea.  I would think that this would be faster, but maybe not possible?

Comment: No, there is no way. You have to do it in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was too good to be true.  I may be able to store some neighbour info in the green, blue and alpha channel's anyway which will reduce the amount of calls to TexelFetch.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know the context, but [`textureGrad`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureGrad.xhtml) or [partial derivatives](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dFdx.xhtml) may help.